# ^([^.?]+)$ and ^(\w+)$ in htaccess rewrite rule explanation

Tags: .htaccess

My problem is I'm confused between the dot(.) and the \w in htaccess some website says the dot is any character what so ever or any single arbitrary character and the slash w `(\w)` is  matches any alphanumeric character and underscores. Can some explain this to me. I'm sorry for the question i just want to learn htaccess coding and can someone differentiate this to me `^(\w+)$`  and `^([^.?]+)$`. Im Hoping for your detailed explanation guys. Thank you !

```
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]


RewriteRule ^(\w+) %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

I need some detailed explanation for this guys. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `\w` alphanumeric characters refer to characters from A-Z both upper and lowercase, and also the numbers 0-9. This also includes underscores as well. Hence it will match any letter, number or underscore. Whereas the dot will match literally any character whether it be a letter, number, symbol (?#$&!), a space. The dot will match any charater you can think of.

Therefore the difference between `^(\w+)$` and `^([^.?]+)$` is this:

`^(\w+)$` will match:

apple

20apples

gr3at

1_boss

It will **not** match:

1 boss <-- Because of the space

$hady <-- Because of the dollar sign

happy feet <-- Because of the space

*However* `^([^.?]+)$` will match all the above statements, even if all you had were spaces, it would match

Comment: Thank you sir . I completely understand now. Thank you so much. :)